# S3TransferManager-Sample | IAM getList policy issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am having this error in my getList call:

S3TransferManagerSample[1717:48308] listObjects failed: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 1.)" UserInfo=0x7fb71412d300 {HostId=qhjcOyYAPQjHhJIX5REMTN5A48ecxIkHCqt6fFwkQPBff+tKWnML9A4yQobq2C38, Message=Access Denied, Code=AccessDenied, RequestId=B6920900AB17C864}]

I have created 2 roles one is auth and other is un-auth. Here are the inline policies for both roles:

```
RoleARN: Cognito_(projectName)Auth_Role
oneClick_Cognito_(projectName)Auth_Role_1424434616386: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
}

policygen-Cognito_(projectName)Auth_Role-201502201739: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1424435859000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::(bucket name)/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

RoleARN: Cognito_(projectName)Unauth_Role
oneClick_Cognito_(projectName)Unauth_Role_1424434555837: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
}

policygen-Cognito_(projectName)Unauth_Role-201502201743: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1424436103000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::(bucket name)/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

can someOne please guide me through?

Answer (score 2):

`ListBucket` permission needs to be granted for a bucket, not for the keys in the bucket. You should take a look at [this blog](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VRSWZ6B3SHAV/Writing-IAM-Policies-How-to-grant-access-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket) for further details.